# java, counting the numbers entered by the user

Tags: java

it doesn't count the second number entered by the user. I tried other things but still can get to it.

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  int count = 0;
  int num = in.nextInt();
  int num2 = in.nextInt();

    if (num > 0){
        count++;
    }
     else if (num2 > 0){
              count++;
    }
 
     System.out.println(count);
```

*input: 2 21435 expected ouput: 2*

Comment: what do you think `else` means in the `else if` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (num > 0){
    count++;
}
else if (num2 > 0){
    count++;
}
```

is about equivalent to  (perhaps, it will make it clearer for you)

```
if (num > 0){
    count++;
}
else {
    // this block is entered only if "num <= 0"!
    if (num2 > 0){
        count++;
    }
}
```

So, if your first test passes, the second will never be executed. Thus, you only ever have one increment tops.

What you want is more like

```
if (num > 0){
    count++;
}
if (num2 > 0){
    count++;
}
```

Here, the second condition gets evaluated, regardless of what the first has been evaluated to.

Comment: how do i make it to count negative number also ?

Comment: How do you want them to be counted? Or just `!= 0`? @Jonny

Comment: i already got to count the negative number, but I still fail the 2 other hidden test in codechum.

Comment: I don't know about any "hidden tests" nor "codechum", sorry.

Answer (score 0):

to check and count each number separately you need to define condition for each variable:

```
if (num > 0) {
    count++;
} 
if (num2 > 0) {
    count++;
}
```

and you can abbreviate it much better like:

```
count += num > 0 ? 1 : 0;
count += num2 > 0 ? 1 : 0;
```